# trailing Space issue in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a varchar column having values with extra space (one,two or many more)  at leading trail of the character.

I tried to remove the spaces with all replace,rtrim,patindex,charindex but didn’t have a luck.

Comment: add some sample data

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: it's sql server

Comment: RTRIM should remove trailing spaces. Likely they are not spaces. Provide an MCVE

Comment: Are you sure it is a space, and not some other non-printable character?

Comment: Confident in space that the character(s) at the end aren't a simple white space, but some other character, as Mark said. To the OP, copy and paste some of the data you have into your question so we can find out what characters they are please.

Comment: Please find some sample data:315309.54
103958.4
144000.00  
4284.00  
3731
83804.00  
1033.00  
3731.00

Comment: convert your data to varbinary...see what the bytes looks like...if its not 20 at the end (ascii 32)...its not a space

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column_name = REPLACE(Column_name, ' ', '')
```

Comment: it's not working as column may have more than 1 trailing spaces randomly

Comment: did you try this 
`SET Column_name  = LTRIM(RTRIM('Column_name  '))`

Answer (score 0):

If it is really space try using `LTRIM(RTRIM(Column_name))`. Alternatively, use some other function to treat a non-printable character:
Use char2hexint to check what that value is:

```
SEL val1, CHAR2HEXINT(val1) AS char2hexint_val1
FROM
mytable;

val1    char2hexint_val1
9 3900
```

In this case *'9'* was the leading character. 
You can also explore the [`COLLATE` function for non-printable character](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1671530-392-1.aspx) detection too.